# Suppressing output from my Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I have ;

```
 default :
           gcc -o function function.c
```

When I type make in terminal, following message is emitted

```
         user@user-laptop:~/Desktop$ make
         gcc -o function function.c 
         user@user-laptop:~/Desktop$
```

But I want

```
         user@user-laptop:~/Desktop$ make
         user@user-laptop:~/Desktop$
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use an `@` to quiet the output:

```
default:
    @gcc -o ...
```

You can find the documentation here: [Recipe echoing](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Echoing). (Or you can invoke `make` with `make -s` to suppress all echoing.)

Answer (score 16):

You can use `make --silent` (at least for GNU make)

Answer (score 3):

To tell Make to be quiet/silent for all the targets, put the following at the top of a Makefile, which will work as though `make --silent` was used without requiring one to provide the switch on command line.

Works with GNU Make on Linux, I am not sure about all the other Make variants.

```
MAKEFLAGS += --silent
```